# Numpy and mypy type annotation - npt.NDArray dtype not being checked

Tags: numpy, mypy, typing

I was trying to perform a type check for a function that accepts both float or np.ndarray[np.float].

Mypy does not complain of any of the following implementations:

```
from typing import Union
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt

_T = Union[float, npt.NDArray[np.float64]]

def func(a: _T) -> _T:
    return a

a = np.array([1])
func(a)

b = np.array([True])
func(b)

c = np.array([""])
func(c)
```

Shouldn't mypy complain about the dtype being different from `np.float64`?

I already found workarounds for the solution of my problem. But I would like to know why the above code does not work.

Comment: Did you turn on numpy's mypy plugin? https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/typing.html#mypy-plugin. *Without the plugin the precision of all relevant classes will be inferred as `Any`*.

Comment: Yes, I created the "mypy.ini" file as proposed in the article. What is your ouput when you run mypy for this code? Is it concerning about the type?

Comment: Ah, it looks like you have to either (1) pass `dtype` explicitly or (2) annotate the assignment for the dtype to be recognised. If you do `b = np.array([True], dtype=np.bool_)` or `c: npt.NDArray[np.str_] = np.array([""])` you can get the errors to show up at `func(...)`.

Comment: I got it. Although it works it seems to be very verbose to explicitly define these types every type for mypy check them :/

Comment: I suppose if you add overloads similar to [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7f1c8cbe0c6fa4e554b3b1e4d7dc2f03fababbec/numpy/_core/multiarray.pyi#L191-L200) it'll work out - except that it'll be `object: _ArrayLike[float]` corresponding to a return of `_ArrayLike[np.float_]`. The maintainers would have to add these for `int`, `bool`, ..., and they just probably didn't bother with the repetitiveness.